# today Datetime as default in lightning-input type="datetime"

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime, inputfield

Hello everybody I amd trying to get today's datetime in tha next field:
[image]

The problem is that I am not getting the HH:mm

I have the next .js code:

```
dateval;

get dateValue(){
if(this.dateval == undefined)
{
  this.dateval = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
}
return this.dateval;
}

changedate(event){
 this.dateval = event.target.value;
       }
```

And the .html:

```
                        <lightning-input type="datetime"  label="Fecha Solicitud"  required value={dateValue} name="fechaSolicitud" onchange={handleFechaSolicitud}></lightning-input>
```

Could anybody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example

value should be in the "2020-09-12T18:13:41Z" format

please remove `substring(0, 10);`

should be

```
this.dateval = new Date().toISOString();
```

Thanks